# Three20 TTLauncherView Tutorial?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, three20

I'm attempting to use TTLauncherView from the Facebook Three20 project in my app, but I'm not having much luck (I'm a bit of a newbie at this). Does anyone have any good tutorials at using it that I could read?

FYI basically I need to pull images that a user chooses from the iPhone camera album, and display them as icons that when pressed lead to another view.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm collecting ideas for Three20 tutorials [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463651/what-needs-to-be-covered-in-three20-tutorials-and-documentation). You should add this, with the questions you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can start studying TTCatalog sample project that comes with three20 library. 
Right now I'm working with a improved version of the three20 made by Rodrigo Mazzilli, you can find it here (http://github.com/rodmaz/three20). 
rodmaz's version is a fork from the original project and it comes with some improvements, specially in TTLauncherView. It has a new class called TTLauncherViewController which is easier to use, take a look at his demo project TTCatalog.

http:// three20.info/ is a good collaborative site with some tutorials, but it doesn't have much information about TTLauncherView at this moment.

Finally, you should join three20's google group at http:// groups.google.com/group/three20 where you find hundreds of developers using this library.

best

Answer (score 4):

http://iosguy.com/2010/10/19/tthree20-a-brief-ttlauncherview-tutorial/